# What is no-probe-top in Cadence OrCAD

Tags: pcb, orcad, cadence, allegro

There is a rectangle around the outside of my OrCAD footprint (pointed to with the blue arrow), and it is on the no-probe-top layer. I googled it but I couldn't find any explanation of what that layer is. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very dependent on the process, but likely that is a virtual layer that is used by the foundry to indicate to them that any top-side pads covered by said layer is not meant to be probed during any testing.

Comment: What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: One reason I could think of is that probe marks on a pad can cause a failure for an automatic optical inspection tool (false yield failures), or perhaps make it difficult to bond a wire to the pad.